# Silex cant display images as response

Tags: php, silex

I can't display any response as image. I have tryed silex method and pure PHP, like this

```
   $file = '1465797900_yoda.png';


    if (!file_exists('images/'.$file)) {
    return $app->abort(404, 'The image was not found.');
}

$stream = function () use ($file) {
    readfile($file);
};

return $app->stream($stream, 200, array('Content-Type' => 'image/png'));
```

or pure PHP:

```
   $file = 'images/1465797900_yoda.png';
$type = 'image/png';
header('Content-Type:'.$type);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
echo readfile($file);
```

If I use method 1 my response is blank image but method 2 return random track, like this:

J���j��?�'T|֢1���Kc�Zu�#��9�G��<��!4#�D�xU�� � á_PW�Fܽ�!rŨ%��Gs�u6�?0�_ �o.>IEND�B`�

Pure PHP dont have problems, only Silex.
Thanks for help.

Comment: if you put image link in a <img> block , any problem friend?

Comment: Well your code seems to match that which is in the Silex docs, so that's curious (I've never tried to do this myself). Have you tried the technique shown here: http://whateverthing.com/blog/2013/06/30/quick-web-apps-part-two/#the-viewer (that was just a random result from googling).

Comment: @AniruddhaChakraborty yes. but i need to encrypt my images, so i shouldn't pass image to img src.

Comment: @AdamCameron yes i have tryed. i have the same result. image is blank.

Comment: Can you pls provide us with a complete (but pared down; nothing that's not germane to the issue) demonstration of your code that is not working. Something we can drop into a vanilla Silex site and see for ourselves? (eg: as per sscce.org). Include everything from the routing through the complete controller. And are you simply hitting the URL in a browser address bar, or calling it from within a view in your site? if the latter, include that code too.

Answer (score 1):

i have written the following for giving Pics from a folder:

```
public function getpic( $id ) {
    $path = '/assets/userpics/' . $id;
    if ( is_file( $path ) ) {
        return new BinaryFileResponse( $path );
    }
    //make some error stuff
}
```

in the Html where you call the image use  or load it via js

Comment: You mean this? $src_tag = "<img src=".$this->getpic()."/>"

Comment: no, i have added a route to call getpic($id), for example /pic/{$id}
and than you have your html/twig files where you have something like <img src="/pic/5">

Comment: I still dont know why this solution doesn't work but now I have my repo in other domain, in new silex project. Anyway, thanks for help :)